# Drawing triangle, can't set normal

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm an experienced C++ programmer tying to learn OpenGL. Among others, I'm reading Richard Wright's *OpenGL Super Bible*. The support libraries there are hacker-head C, loosely translated into C++. Being a bit of a purist, I've translated most of the support code into C++. And I'm working in QT rather than Glut. I've gotten the examples from Chapter 2 and the "Primitives" example from Chapter 3 working, but can't get the "GeoTest" example to work right. Here's a simplified example of the problem:

```
void geotest::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    model_view_matrix.push(view_frame);
        float red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        shader.use(
            transform_pipeline.get_model_view_matrix(),
            transform_pipeline.get_projection_matrix(),
            red);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f(-1.2f, -1.2f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f( 1.2f, -1.2f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f( 1.2f,  1.2f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();
    model_view_matrix.pop();
}
```

The `shader` is my adaptation of the book's `GLT_SHADER_DEFAULT_LIGHT`. I've cut down the drawing to isolate the problem. When I run this code I get a seemingly blank window. The code that I haven't shows provides support for rotating the image, and when I rotate it 180 degrees around the x or y axis I see the other side of the triangle, but it's black instead of red. So it looks like the surface normal is initially pointing away from the viewer, so it gets culled.

I've tried adding 1 to 3 calls to `glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)` (and `1.0f`) everywhere I could imagine between the `glBegin` and `glEnd` calls, with no effect that I could see; the triangle is always drawn with its back face showing.

Am I missing something fundamental about normals? I'm pretty sure that the shader is okay (I get the same problem with the normal if I use the book's GLT_SHADER_FLAT, although when the triangle appears it's red, as it should be).

EDIT here's the code for the shader:

```
const char *default_light_vp = "uniform mat4 mvMatrix;"
                               "uniform mat4 pMatrix;"
                               "varying vec4 vFragColor;"
                               "attribute vec4 vVertex;"
                               "attribute vec3 vNormal;"
                               "uniform vec4 vColor;"
                               "void main(void) { "
                               " mat3 mNormalMatrix;"
                               " mNormalMatrix[0] = mvMatrix[0].xyz;"
                               " mNormalMatrix[1] = mvMatrix[1].xyz;"
                               " mNormalMatrix[2] = mvMatrix[2].xyz;"
                               " vec3 vNorm = normalize(mNormalMatrix * vNormal);"
                               " vec3 vLightDir = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0); "
                               " float fDot = max(0.0, dot(vNorm, vLightDir)); "
                               " vFragColor.rgb = vColor.rgb * fDot;"
                               " vFragColor.a = vColor.a;"
                               " mat4 mvpMatrix;"
                               " mvpMatrix = pMatrix * mvMatrix;"
                               " gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex; "
                               "}";


const char *default_light_fp =   
#ifdef OPENGL_ES
                               "precision mediump float;"
#endif
                               "varying vec4 vFragColor; "
                               "void main(void) { "
                               " gl_FragColor = vFragColor; "
                               "}";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Culling isn't based on the direction of the normals, it's based on the winding order. Try switching the direction that you are drawing your vertices, and see if that makes a difference. To change the winding order, you can use `glFrontFace` with `GL_CW` and `GL_CCW`, which defines which face is front and which is back.

Comment: Thanks; interchanging the last two calls to `glVertex3f` made the triangle show up when the program starts. Now I have to figure out why everything is black instead of red. But that's a different question. <g>

Comment: Straight from the book's sources. Added to the question. The *real* code creates a torus, with vertices and normals for all of its triangles, code lifted from the book's sources. Same problem there: it's all black.

Comment: Maybe try reversing the light direction?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The original code (with Glut and the book's library) works, and I think I've been pretty faithful in adapting it. The light source for this particular shader is supposed to be at the eye point. It does require a normal for each surface (which is why I originally blamed normals), but the code that draws the torus (the un-simplified version) provides normals, and all the surfaces are black in my version, but colored appropriately in the original. So I'll have to dig some more.